# Small chokes of 4k videos on YouTube

Tags: video, crash, gpu, youtube

Good night. I noticed that when I try to run a 2160p (4k) video on Ubuntu 20.04, the YouTube video starts to experience slight crashes. The same process does not occur in Windows 10.

Furthermore, this problem only occurs at 2160p (4k) resolution, because at 1440p the problem does not happen.

[My specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqw1L.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what version of Ubuntu you're using and what browser you're using - and please include the browser version as well. The version is usually available with the `-version` switch in the terminal. e.g. `Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105`.

Comment: Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: In your settings, do you have 'hardware acceleration' enabled?

Comment: Hardware acceleration are enabled.

Comment: Disable it, restart your browser, and check to see if the problem still exists. Browsers in Linux generally don't work well with HA, but the option is there in browsers and frequently causes weird bugs, system crashes, etc... Disabling it won't harm anything and may fix it.